# What data should I care when retrieving only the contents of a HTML webpage?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

We all know that the contents of an HTML page aren't just the data between open and closed tags, for example, `<p></p>`.

Beyond image "alt" and any "title" attributes, what HTML offer to me that I should consider as a content?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on what you plan to do with the data.  If in doubt, just save everything.

Comment: I want to classify the text as porn or not porn, for example

Comment: If you want to scrutinize the text-only, view my answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question. From the downvote and the close votes, I think I'm not the only one. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

#### Getting Your Text...

Titles (`<h1>` - `<h6>`), images (`<img />`), paragraphs (`<p>`) and links (`<a>`). Not much more than that. Unless you want to count tables too.

If you want to pull all of the text from the Body, you can do so easily with a scraper-tool like [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (requires PHP):

```
phpQuery::newDocument(file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com"));
$body = pq("body")->text();
print $body;
```

In that example, $text would be the total content of your entire page. You could then search for keywords in there to help you determine the content.

#### Scanning Your Text for Keywords...

As you stated in your comment, you're wanting to guard against porn-url's being submitted. Using this method, you can get the text. Once you have the text, you could scan it and build a list of keywords/instances. That list should give you a good idea about the content/subject of the page (unless the page is just a video of some sort).

To learn how you can build these keywords/instances list, view the following Question:
[Quickly Build List of Keywords from Text, Including # of Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038252/code-golf-quickly-build-list-of-keywords-from-text-including-of-instances)